# wordpress user registration/profile plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress site which will allow users to register by themselves and log into the site and have a profile. IS there such a plugin that will allow me to incorporate this into my site? I have looked around and being that I have very little experience with making sites/wordpress I have decided to ask some experts.

I know with wordpress you get a "blog" sort of site, but i'm hoping that if the plug-in i'm looking for exists then I can make my site to look different. The reason I am asking for each individual member to have their own "profile page/ private page" is because I want to be able to upload data to their specific pages and they should be able to see the data without seeing others'.

Thanks for any and all help you can provide me. 
If I can't find a suitable solution, I will try to build a site with joomla, I had gone with wordpress because I had heard that it was easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, There is one plugin to do all these in wordpress. Plugin name: **Profile Builder - front-end user registration, login and edit profile**

plugin Link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, There is one plugin to do with all the things which you want. **Plugin Name :** "*Theme My Login*"

***Plugin Features :***

- Your registration, log in, and password recovery pages will all match
  the rest of your website
- Includes a customizable widget to login anywhere from your blog
- Redirect users upon log in and log out based upon their role
- Show gravatar to users who are logged in.
- Assign custom links to users who are logged in based on their role
- Customize user emails for registration and/or password recovery
- Send user emails in HTML format
- Allow users to set their own password upon registration
- Require users to be approved or confirm e-mail address upon
  registration
- Theme user profiles

***Please refer the following Location :***

[Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)